# Type deduction in templated functions and const quailifier

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have the following piece of c++11-code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct object {
    void talk(const char* text) const { std::cout << "talk " << text << std::endl; }
};

void makeItTalk(object& obj) { obj.talk("non-const"); }
void makeItTalk(const object& obj) { obj.talk("const"); }

template<typename P> void f(P&& p) { 
    makeItTalk(std::forward<P>(p));
}


int main() {

    const object obj;
    f(obj);

    return 0;
}
```

When running I get `talk const` which is what it should be, but I'm wondering how it works. From what I read so far the `const`-qualifier is ignored in template deduction. Since `obj` is of type `const object&` and we have a `P&&` as parameter in `f` I would expect that the template parameter resolves to `object&` and since `& && = &` the function `f` should become

```
void f(object& p) { makeItTalk(std::forward<object&>(p)); }
```

But this function is not even allowed to be called for `obj`. So I'm wondering if I am wrong by saying the `const` is ignored?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding exactly what you're asking, but as far as I know, forwarding constness is an intended effect of `std::forward`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, type deduction does not ignore the const qualifier when the function template takes a pointer or reference parameter. The top-level consts are removed but not the constness of what is pointed to or referenced.

A more extensive argument can be found here: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/04/appearing-and-disappearing-consts-in-c/