# Checking whether we have a const type

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have the following c++11-code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void overload(T&& t);
template<> void overload<char&>(char& t) { std::cout << "char& called" << std::endl; }
template<> void overload<const char&>(const char& t) { std::cout << "const char& called" << std::endl; }

int main() {

    std::cout << "const char: " << ((std::is_const<const char>::value)?"const":"non-const") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "const char&: " << ((std::is_const<const char&>::value)?"const":"non-const") << std::endl;

    const char c = 'c';
    overload(c);

    return 0;
}
```

When running I get

```
const char: const
const char&: non-const
const char& called
```

I'm wondering why the second call to `std::is_const` does not see the constness whereas the call to overload does see it.

Any Thoughts?

This question is highly related to this one:
[Type deduction in templated functions and const quailifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340840/type-deduction-in-templated-functions-and-const-quailifier) but still a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to confuse levels of constness.

is_const correctly reports that the type lacks the top-level const (`const char&const` would be true if legal).

Your overload matches the correct function on constness left to &.

Try the same thing with pointers, `char*`, `const char*`, `char* const` and `const char*const` to see the levels better.

Comment: Thanks! That was the hint I needed. Also thanks to the other comments.

Answer (score 1):

What has to be said about top-level const has been said in the comments and other answer. How you get what you probably would like to see: use `std::remove_reference`

```
std::is_const<std::remove_reference<const char&>::type>::value
```